# Generate number of arrays from one array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am working on project in vb.net, I have an integer array for example (1,8,9,8), what I need is to generate number of arrays from it by add 1 to each item at a time so that the first array suppose to be (2,8,9,8) and the second (1,9,9,8) and so on, I tried this code:

```
Function myarray(ByVal arra1() As Integer, ByVal arran() As Integer, ByVal i As Integer) As Integer
    For i = 0 To arra1.Length - 
        arran(i) = arra1(i)
        arran(i) = arra1(i) + 1
      Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much I understand from the question in current given context this may be your required solution:

```
Function myarray(ByVal arra1() As Integer, ByVal arran() As Integer, ByVal arrNumber As Integer) As Integer
    arran=arra1.Clone()
    For i As Integer = 0 To arra1.Length - 1
        If i = (arrNumber - 1) Then ' IF arrNumber is 1 then +1 to index 0, If it is 2 then +1 to index 1
            arran(i) = arra1(i) + 1
        Else
            arran(i) = arra1(i)
        End If
    Next
    'Print the array
    For i = 0 To arran.Length - 1
        Console.Write(arran(i) & " ")
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
    Return 0
End Function
```

You can call it as

```
Dim a3() As Integer={1,8,9,8}
Dim a4() As Integer={}
myarray(a3,a4,1)
myarray(a3,a4,2)
myarray(a3,a4,3)
myarray(a3,a4,4)
```

When you call this function with arra1 as (1,8,9,8)
and arrNumber as 1 then arran will be (2,8,9,8),
with arrNumber as 2 then arran will be (1,9,9,8),
with arrNumber as 3 then arran will be (1,8,10,8) and
with arrNumber as 4 then arran will be (1,8,9,9)

Comment: Thank's haraman, but I got exception at this point ...If i = (arrNumber - 1) Then '

Comment: sorry I get (Object reference not set to an instance of an object).at arran(i)=arr1(i)  not in what I said before

Comment: @rasha That was just an example of how you can achieve your requirement using this minimal code guide. You have to implement it in your code as per your requirement. So it was assumed that you would initialize `arran` and print it or use it any other way you want. Check updated code

Comment: your code is really what I need ,so I try to make some change in your function as below

Comment: your code was  what  i need really I Try to make some changes to it so that if in the same array appear the same value it will be  decomposed into two array like that  {1,4,5,5} will be {1,4,0,5} and {1,4,5,0 }                                                                                                                If i = (arrNumber - 1) then
   arran(i) = arra1(i) + 1
   For k = 0 To arran.Length - 1
  For j = k + 1 To arran.Length - 1
       If arran(k) = arran(j) Then
 arran(k) = 0

Comment: That's great. As your new criteria is different from this question, if you need any help you may ask it as a new question post. *This post and an accepted answer may help others to find a solution to similar problems*. You should also read [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/306969)

Answer (score 0):

First declare your initial array.

```
' declare initial array
Dim arr1 = {1, 8, 9, 8}
```

Then declare a jagged array for the result. Since the initial array has 4 elements, it will create a 4 arrays.

```
' declare a jagged array for the result
Dim result(arr1.Length - 1)() As Integer
```

Then you clone the initial array, and only change one of the value.

```
For i = 0 To arr1.Length - 1

  ' clone the initial array
  result(i) = arr1.Clone()

  ' only change the element at index = i
  result(i)(i) += 1

Next
```

**Result is:**

```
2 8 9 8 
1 9 9 8 
1 8 10 8 
1 8 9 9
```

**Full source:**

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        ' declare initial array
        Dim arr1 = {1, 8, 9, 8}

        ' declare a jagged array for the result
        Dim result(arr1.Length - 1)() As Integer

        For i = 0 To arr1.Length - 1

            ' clone the initial array
            result(i) = arr1.Clone()

            ' only change the element at index = i
            result(i)(i) += 1

        Next

        ' print result
        For i = 0 To result.Length - 1
            For j = 0 To result(i).Length - 1
                Console.Write(result(i)(j) & " ")
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next

        Console.ReadKey(True)

    End Sub

End Module
```

**In case you want to make a function.**

```
Function CopyArray(ByVal source As Integer(), i As Integer) As Integer()

    ' clone the initial array
    Dim temp = source.Clone()

    ' only change the element at index = i
    temp(i) += 1

    Return temp

End Function
```

You call the function inside the iteration.

```
For i = 0 To arr1.Length - 1

    result(i) = CopyArray(arr1, i)

Next
```

**Full source with function:**

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        ' declare initial array
        Dim arr1 = {1, 8, 9, 8}

        ' declare a jagged array for the result
        Dim result(arr1.Length - 1)() As Integer

        For i = 0 To arr1.Length - 1

            result(i) = CopyArray(arr1, i)

        Next

        ' print result
        For i = 0 To result.Length - 1
            For j = 0 To result(i).Length - 1
                Console.Write(result(i)(j) & " ")
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next

        Console.ReadKey(True)

    End Sub

    Function CopyArray(ByVal source As Integer(), i As Integer) As Integer()

        ' clone the initial array
        Dim temp = source.Clone()

        ' only change the element at index = i
        temp(i) += 1

        Return temp

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,it 's work without function ,but in case of function   it doesn't work

Comment: It works with function. I have tested it. See my edit.

Comment: And I didn't change anything. Maybe you didn't initialize the array first. I omit the initialize part because I have explained it in the first solution (without function).